# How to run a Selenium+Java+Maven project that is hosted on Azure DevOps server directly with Jenkins?

Tags: automated-testing, jenkins, tfs, jenkins-pipeline, build

I have made a Cucumber based BDD - Selenium, Java, Maven, TestNG Automation framework that has it's source code hosted on Azure DevOps (formally TFS).

Now, I have a corporate Jenkins server and I want to run my project directly by the running the Jenkins job and want to see the logs and reports on Jenkins itself.

Can I do that as Under "Build" section? I give my path to the pom.xml of the project but that is on my local. How can I give path of Azure DevOps project repository so that anyone in my team can run the Automated Test without worrying about configuration or code changes?

Also, I want to run the latest code that is available in TFS. I am a complete beginner in Jenkins CI/CD, DevOps etc.

Please suggest something or refer to some good resource.
Thanks!